# Chrome DevTools Workspace Enable Wildcard in Mapping

Tags: google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to add a wildcard to Chrome DevTools.

The website that I'm working on has a cache busting function which is outputting the css to a new 'folder' every time, like this '/stylesheets/v~1464156943955/global.css'.

I want to be able to map the files using a wildcard so that when the sass is compiled and refreshed it retains the mapping.

`https://localhost:4000/stylesheets/*/global.css/ => /sass/global.scss/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it doesn't seem like it's possible. See this open issue about it on the Chrome bug tracker:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277885

It seems like they are still considering it, so there's hope yet!